# Lambda Expression Find Top/Bottom Key based on Value in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

.NET Framework 4.6.

Given this SortedDictionary:

```
var mydict =  new SortedDictionary<int, int> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {4, 14}, {8, 33}, {16, 0}, {32, 0} , {64,0} };
```

I am trying to find key "16" because it is the first key with a value of 0 that comes after the last non-zero-valued key.

Given this SortedDictionary:

```
var mydict =  new SortedDictionary<int, int> {{1, 0}, {2, 8}, {4, 0}, {8, 33}, {16, 11}, {32, 0} , {64,0} };
```

I would want to find the key of 32.

I understand how to do this with enumerating and temp variables, but I am asking for something slick with a Lambda.

All ideas appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply start at the end with `Reverse` then go while the value is 0 (`TakeWhile`) and grab the key (`Select`) of the last item (`LastOrDefault`).

```
var key = mydict.Reverse()
                .TakeWhile(kvp => kvp.Value == 0)
                .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
                .LastOrDefault();
```

By the way, this is called Linq, not lambda, though lambdas are used as part of Linq.

Comment: I did not want a vanilla Linq query expression, I wanted a Lambda expression, which you provided. Thanks! I do understand the difference which is why I asked for what I asked for.

Comment: @Snowy OK, this is called method syntax vs query syntax, which I'm guessing is what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict
    .SkipWhile(x => x.Key == 0)
    .Where(x => x.Value == 0)
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This would not work for something like {1,0}, {2,2}, {3,0}, {4,5}, {5,0} as it would select 3 instead of 5.

Comment: @juharr yep, I missed the part about "after the last non-zero-valued key."